# Meteor launching stuck on "Building for web.browser"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, macos, meteor, ionic-framework

I'm currently beginning with Ionic and Meteor on my MacBook.

I'm following a tutorial from the official website of AngularJs.
I followed every step of this tutorial, but I encounter a problem when I launch my app with "sudo meteor". 
It gets stuck at "Building for web.browser". I searched on the internet any solution but I can't find anything.

Before I followed this step "http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/authentication" it worked perfectly.

I hope I can find a solution here. Thanks !

Comment: Are there any crash reports? I'd expect meteor to timeout after a certain amount of time. Also, why are you using sudo? Meteor should be fine to run without sudo.